# Using logistic regression for a multiple touch response model (python/pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have a bunch of contact data listing what members were contacted by what offer, which summarizes something like this:

[image]

To make sense of it (and to make it more scalable) I was considering creating dummy variables for each offer and then using a logistic model to see how different offers impact performance:

[image]

Before I embark too far on this journey I wanted to get some input if this is a sensible way to approach this (I have started playing around but and got a model output, but haven't dug into it yet). Someone suggested I use linear regression instead, but I'm not really sure about the approach for that in this case.

What I'm hoping to get are coefficients that are interpretable - so I can see that Mailing the 50% off offer in the 3d mailing is not as impactful as the $25 giftcard etc, and then do this at scale (lots of mailings with lots of different offers) to draw some conclusions about the impact of timing of different offers.

My concern is that I will end up with a fairly sparse matrix where only some combinations of the many possible are respresented, and what problems may arise from this. I've taken some online courses in ML but am new to it, and this is one of my first chances to work directly with it so I'm hoping I could create something useful out of this. I have access to lots and lots of data, it's just a matter of getting something basic out that can show some value. Maybe there's already some work on this or even some kind of library I can use?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If your target variable is binary (1 or 0) as in the second chart, then a classification model is appropriate. Logistic Regression is a good first option, you could also a tree-based model like a decision tree classifier or a random forest.

Creating dummy variables is a good move; you could also convert the discounts to numerical values if you want to keep them in a single column, however this may not work so well for a linear model like logistic regression as the correlation will probably not be linear.

If you wanted to model the first chart directly you could use a linear regressions for predicting the conversion rate, I'm not sure about the difference is in doing this, it's actually something I've been wondering about for a while, you've motivated me to [post a question on stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242175/difference-between-logistic-regression-and-linear-regression-on-aggregated-datas)